# Why Blazor @onclick not working inside hoverable html element content but @onmousedown works?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net5

In my `blazor` `webassembly` app, I'm using `bulma` `dropdown` component and I have `Log out` `button` inside togglable dropdown content.

Here is the html of my `Log out` button.

```
<div id="userMenu" class="dropdown is-right @(UserMenuCollapsed ? "is-active" : null)" @onclick="ToggleUserMenu" @onfocusout="FocusOutHandler">
    <div class="dropdown-trigger p-1">
        <button class="bg-green-300 rounded-full h-10 w-10 flex items-center justify-center border-none cursor-pointer" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="user-menu">AR</button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <NavLink href="/profile" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" class="dropdown-item">
                Profile (@context.User.Identity.Name)
            </NavLink>
            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            <button class="dropdown-item" @onclick="BeginSignOut">Log out</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This piece of html get displayed when I click `#userMenu` `div` element. Now when I click `Log out` button nothing happens.

On googling I found like sometime changing `@onclick` to `@onmousedown` will make click action to work. I changed and it got worked. But not sure why. Please can anyone explain what happens under the hood?

**Update 1:**
After reading @Umair comments, I have tried to use `event stop propagation` but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is the updated code:

```
<div id="userMenu" class="dropdown is-right @(UserMenuCollapsed ? "is-active" : null)" @onclick="ToggleUserMenu" @onfocusout="FocusOutHandler">
    <div class="dropdown-trigger p-1">
        <button class="bg-green-300 rounded-full h-10 w-10 flex items-center justify-center border-none cursor-pointer" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="user-menu">AR</button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <NavLink href="/profile" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" class="dropdown-item">
                Profile (@context.User.Identity.Name)
            </NavLink>
            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            <button class="dropdown-item" @onclick="BeginSignOut" @onclick:stopPropagation="stopPropagation">Log out</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private bool stopPropagation = false;
}
```

Comment: My best guess is that you have an @onclick on the outer div and also on the button hence the outer div is blocking the one below?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I tried [Event Stop Propagation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#stop-event-propagation) but that doesn't help. Any idea on why?

Comment: But stopping event propagation will actually stop clicking the button.

Comment: [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) says "It does not, however, prevent any default behaviors from occurring; for instance, clicks on links are still processed"

Comment: If you try to put button outside div `userMenu`,can it work?

Comment: Putting it outside will make button not available inside drop-down menu